# AFNetworking reachability is always unknown

Tags: ios, reachability, afnetworking-2

I start monitoring like this in my AppDelegate:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

On my root controller I then need to check if reachability is available and I perform this action to decide how to draw my UI:

```
AFNetworkReachabilityManager *manager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager];
NSLog(@"%s - %@", __FUNCTION__, AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus([manager networkReachabilityStatus]));
switch ([manager networkReachabilityStatus]){
    case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
        [self showNetworkUnreachable];
        break;
    default:
        [self hideNetworkUnreachable];
}
```

My issue is that here status is always unknown even if the device has connection.

Possibly AfNetworking is not the right tool to be used here. Any suggestion?

Comment: I've never used AFNetworking to check the reachability, but I can't see anywhere the domain you are trying to reach. Pretty sure you have to deal with `+ (instancetype)managerForDomain:(NSString *)domain;`. Apple also suggest a reachability class : https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html

Comment: I guess Reachability my be more suited to this kind of needs. I will test it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not working in my case too. I used [that](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_m.html) instead:

```
- (BOOL)isInternetConnectionAvailable
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (internetStatus != NotReachable) {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NO INTERNET CONNECTION");
        return NO;
    }
}
```